# Problem with passing a parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I've got a full page lightbox with a slideshow gallery and I am trying to refactor my code so I will not have to use a global variable. I'm straggling with passing a variable as a parameter from function to function. It all works well when I open the lightbox gallery: the correct image is seen and the number in the counter is shown. The problem starts when I want to switch to next or previous image. I can't access the variable which stores or stored the current image seen when the lightbox was open.
I'm posting my simplified code without variables' declarations.

```
// This is a function which opens the lightbox with the galery after clicking on a thumbnail image.
function openSlideshowLightbox (event, currentSlide) {
  for (const [currentThumbnailImg] of thumbnailImgs.entries()) {
    if (event.target === thumbnailImgs[currentThumbnailImg]) {
      showCurrentSlide(currentSlide = currentThumbnailImg) 
    }
  }
} 

// This function shows the current slide containing an image
function showCurrentSlide (currentSlide) {
  for (const slide of slides) {
    if (slide.classList.contains('slide_visible')) {
      slide.classList.remove('slide_visible')
      slide.classList.add('slide_hidden')
    } else {
      slide.classList.add('slide_hidden')
    }
  }
  slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('slide_hidden')
  slides[currentSlide].classList.add('slide_visible')
}
```

All above is one action, the lightbox gets open and the functions finish their tasks.

Now I want to switch to next or previous image but I don't have access to `currentSlide` variable anymore which I need in the below function.

```
function navigateSlideshowLightbox (event, currentSlide) {
  if (previousImgIconClicked) {
    currentSlide = (currentSlide - 1 + allSlides) % allSlides
    showCurrentSlide(currentSlide)
  } else if (nextImgIconClicked) {
    currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % allSlides
    showCurrentSlide(currentSlide)
  }
}
```

I tried to use `return` statement in `showCurrentSlide()`:

```
return currentSlide
```

and then in `navigateSlideshowLightbox()`:

```
currentSlide = showCurrentSlide()
```

but `currentSlide` is `undefiend`.

Comment: Note that since you are declaring `currentSlide` as a parameter inside your functions, any global variables you have named `currentSlide` will not be recognized within those functions, nor will setting `currentSlide` have any effect on the global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentSlide = showCurrentSlide()` will always return `undefined` if you don't pass an argument to the `showCurrentSlide()` function, even if you add a `return` statement. You need to either pass an argument there e.g. `currentSlide = showCurrentSlide(theSlide)`. Or you can do the following as a quick and easy solution.

In the following function, since you're already using the `slides` object, just add the current slide to the `slides` object at the end, for later:

```
function showCurrentSlide (currentSlide) {
    for (const slide of slides) {
        if (slide.classList.contains('slide_visible')) {
            slide.classList.remove('slide_visible')
            slide.classList.add('slide_hidden')
        } else {
            slide.classList.add('slide_hidden')
        }
    }
    slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('slide_hidden')
    slides[currentSlide].classList.add('slide_visible')
    slides.lastActiveSlide = currentSlide // Adding it here
}
```

Then whe you run the `navigateSlideshowLightbox()` function you can just reach for that object property instead of relying on the paramater.

```
function navigateSlideshowLightbox (event) {
    if (previousImgIconClicked) {
        const currentSlide = (slides.lastActiveSlide - 1 + allSlides) % allSlides
        showCurrentSlide(currentSlide)
    } else if (nextImgIconClicked) {
        const currentSlide = (slides.lastActiveSlide + 1) % allSlides
        showCurrentSlide(currentSlide)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't re-declare a const.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. I declared `currentSlide` with `let` on top of the function and then just redeclared it depending on the condition. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

*(this should really be a comment instead, but running out of space for questions there)*

The statement `currentSlide = showCurrentSlide()` probably does nothing because `showCurrentSlide()` does not return a value. Return the value:

```js
function showCurrentSlide (currentSlide) {
  for (const slide of slides) {
    if (slide.classList.contains('slide_visible')) {
      slide.classList.remove('slide_visible')
      slide.classList.add('slide_hidden')
    } else {
      slide.classList.add('slide_hidden')
    }
  }
  slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('slide_hidden')
  slides[currentSlide].classList.add('slide_visible')
  
  return currentSlide;
}
```

Your function `navigateSlideshowLightbox()` should also `return currentSlide`, since it is modifying it, correct?
Your written description says you tried to use return but it didn't work - post your code as you have it, not as you want it to work.

Another curiosity:

`showCurrentSlide(currentSlide = currentThumbnailImg)`

I would rather write this as two lines.

```js
currentSlide = currentThumbnailImg;
showCurrentSlide(currentSlide);
```

In your current code you don't need the result so why not supply that value directly?

```js
showCurrentSlide(currentThumbnailImg);
```

Comment: Yes, I think it's better to write it like you suggested, on two separate lines `currentSlide = currentThumbnailImg; showCurrentSlide(currentSlide);` I wont need `currentSlide` as a parameter in `openSlideshowLightbox()` and can simply declare it `let currentSlide`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a parameter really. As `navigateSlideshowLightbox()` performs a separate task from `openSlideshowLightbox()`, I iterate over all the slides within `navigateSlideshowLightbox()` and by checking which slide is currently seen I get the needed index position of the slide which I then assign to `currentSlide` variable.

```
function navigateSlideshowLightbox () {
    if (previousImgIconClicked) {
        for (const [slideVisible] of slides.entries()) {
          if (slides[slideVisible].classList.contains('slide_visible')) {
            currentSlide = (slideVisible - 1 + allSlides) % allSlides
          }
        }
        showCurrentSlide(currentSlide)
    } else if (nextImgIconClicked) {
        //  Here comes the same 'for' loop with if statement as above.
        currentSlide = (slideVisible + 1) % allSlides
        showCurrentSlide(currentSlide)
    }
```